# How to use ProcessBuilder with bash -c, if the command has double quotes

Tags: java, bash, join, awk, processbuilder

I have to join two huge files based on multiple columns. Pipe(|) symbol is the delimiter in both files.

Right now, I am generating unix join command, writing it to a shell script and then executing the shell script using ProcessBuilder to get the desired output.

The command looks something like this,

`join -a 1 -a 2 -t \| -1 1 -2 1 -o 1.3,1.4,1.5,1.6,1.7,2.3,2.4,2.5,2.6,2.7 <(<"/home/input file 1" awk -F'|' 'NR>1{print $3"~&~"$4"|"$0}' | sort -k1 -t\| ) <(<"/home/input file 2" awk -F'|' 'NR>1{print $3~&~$4"|"$0}' | sort -k1 -t\| )  > "/home/output file"`

This is working as expected.

I am trying to omit the step of writing the command to a shell script by using **bash -c**. But I am running into issues mainly because of the double quotes(") and dollar($) in the awk command. I tried to escape them using backward slash, but was of no use.

the java code I am using currently is

```
long pid = -1;
try {
    StringBuilder completeCommand = new StringBuilder();
    for(String s: commands){
        completeCommand.append(s);
        completeCommand.append(" ");
    }
    completeCommand.append(" > \"");
    completeCommand.append(outputDir + File.separator + outputFileName);
    completeCommand.append("\"");
    File fileOutputDir = new File(outputDir);
    fileOutputDir.mkdirs();

    Files.writeString(Path.of(outputDir + File.separator + scriptName),
            completeCommand.toString(),
            new OpenOption[]{StandardOpenOption.TRUNCATE_EXISTING, StandardOpenOption.WRITE,
                    StandardOpenOption.CREATE});

    ProcessBuilder processBuilder = new ProcessBuilder("bash", "\"" + outputDir + File.separator + scriptName + "\"");
    Process p = processBuilder.start();
    pid = p.pid();
    p.waitFor();
    return pid;
} catch (IOException | InterruptedException e) {
    log.error("Error in running join command" , e);
    return pid;
}
```

When I tried to use bash -c, I just changed the ProcessBuilder statement like below,

```
ProcessBuilder processBuilder = new ProcessBuilder("bash", "-c", completeCommand.toString());
```

This doesn't throw any error, but it generates an empty file.

Is there any way I can solve this issue ?

Any help or suggestions would be great.

Thanks

Comment: @DuncG, I have edited the question with the corresponding details as requested. Thanks

Comment: The code you posted is **not** a [mcve]. What is variable `commands` in the `for` loop? Remember that usually you need to split the command into separate words and make a `List` or array from those words and pass that `List` (or array) to `ProcessBuilder` constructor. Have you considered writing a shell script and running that script from `ProcessBuilder`?

Comment: @Abra, Right now I am writing the command to a script and executing the script. I am trying to omit that step. Is it possible ? I'll try to repost the code so that it would be minimal and reproducible.

Comment: It is hard to answer without seeing `commands`, most likely to do with escaping. You are ignoring error messages from the launch `processBuilder.redirectOutput(stdout);` and `processBuilder.redirectErrorStream(true);`.